# MySQL - Check if any row in grouped result contains specific empty field

Tags: jquery, mysql

I'm currently re-writing a custom PHP & MySQL based time clock system for our company. I've come up with a script that will show each employees name, total worked time during a specific period, and calculate out their gross pay. However, I would like to add one more field into this result. I want it to be a simple TRUE or FALSE, returning TRUE if any of the rows for a specific employee have an empty `time_out`. This will flag that employee in the admin section that they forgot to punch out and that the timer is still running somewhere.

```
SELECT
e.eid AS eid,
CONCAT(e.last_name, ', ', e.first_name) AS full_name,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(IF(p.time_out IS NULL,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),p.time_out) - p.time_in)) AS time_worked,
CONCAT('$',ROUND(SUM(IF(p.time_out IS NULL,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),p.time_out) - p.time_in) * (e.wage/3600), 2)) AS gross_pay
FROM punches AS p
LEFT JOIN employees AS e ON e.eid = p.eid
WHERE (p.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-05-05')
GROUP BY p.eid
```

Here are the two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employees` (
  `eid` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `last_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `vacation_start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '2100-01-01',
  `wage` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `deleted` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`eid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `eid` (`eid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `employees` (`eid`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `status`, `vacation_start_date`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `wage`, `deleted`) VALUES
    (1, 'Tom', 'Employee', 1, NULL, '2015-04-15', '2100-01-01', 22.00, 0),
    (2, 'Dave', 'Employee', 1, NULL, '2015-04-15', '2100-01-01', 10.00, 0),
    (3, 'Bill', 'Employee', 1, NULL, '2015-04-15', '2100-01-01', 10.00, 0);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `punches` (
  `pid` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eid` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time_in` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_out` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `pid` (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `punches` (`pid`, `eid`, `date`, `time_in`, `time_out`) VALUES
    (84, 1, '2015-04-15', 1429127195, 1429127265),
    (85, 2, '2015-04-15', 1429121213, 1429127267),
    (86, 3, '2015-04-15', 1429124215, 1429127269),
    (90, 2, '2015-04-14', 1429121513, NULL);
```

As you can see, one of the rows in `punches` contains NULL for `time_out`. I'd like to add a column in my result that will show TRUE for the employee with the ID of 2, and the rest of the employees will show FALSE. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX(time_out IS NULL)` to tell whether there were any null `time_out` values in the group.

```
SELECT
    e.eid AS eid,
    CONCAT(e.last_name, ', ', e.first_name) AS full_name,
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(IF(p.time_out IS NULL,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),p.time_out) - p.time_in)) AS time_worked,
    CONCAT('$',ROUND(SUM(IF(p.time_out IS NULL,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),p.time_out) - p.time_in) * (e.wage/3600), 2)) AS gross_pay,
    IF(MAX(time_out IS NULL) = 1, 'true', 'false') AS has_empty_time_out
FROM punches AS p
LEFT JOIN employees AS e ON e.eid = p.eid
WHERE (p.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-05-05')
GROUP BY p.eid
```

Answer (score 0):

I have altered your query a little, tried it in SQL fiddle but only one row appeared in results

```
SELECT
e.eid AS eid,
CONCAT(e.last_name, ', ', e.first_name) AS full_name,
SUBTIME(FROM_UNIXTIME(if (p.time_out is NULL,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(),p.time_out)),FROM_UNIXTIME(p.time_in)) AS time_worked,
CONCAT('$',ROUND((p.time_out - p.time_in) * (e.wage/3600), 2)) AS gross_pay,
if (p.time_out is NOT NULL,'TRUE','FALSE') AS has_time_out
FROM punches AS p
LEFT JOIN employees AS e ON e.eid = p.eid
WHERE (p.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-05-05')
GROUP BY p.eid
```

here's a fiddle of it http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12a65/40

Comment: The fiddle shows 3 rows, but it also says TRUE for all of them, when only employee 2 should be true.

Comment: It fetches only the employees that have a valid time_out, a time_out not null. And i am not summing the time for each employee. Try run the query you posted as answer to see the result. Also try it without the group by eid part in the end.

Comment: That shows 2 rows for Dave. I'm not sure what you're changing, I already got a working answer above. :P

Comment: Yes it shows 2 rows from Dave but please take a good look on your data for the MySQL tables it has two entries on Dave. One is with time_out NULL and one not. I just deleted the GROUP BY eid part on the end of the query that is why it shows 2 entries from Dave.

Comment: But I only want one result per `eid`. This should group up all of their time between the two dates and add it up. If one is NULL, the query will use the current time.